# How to save data in custom table and then send that data in order email in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.3

Anyone can please help me how to save data in a custom table after successful order and send saved data in order email.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` at

> Namespace\module\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="mymodule_controller_success_action" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\MyObserver"  />
</event>
```